# Unable to open an excel file using Ajax download

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

In controller, I am reading string buffer with comma separated and using apache poi library, generating Excel Content. I send the excel content to Ajax call to have browser download the excel file. I am able to download the file but when I open it in excel it errors out.

Controller code:

```java
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    @RestController
    public class ExcelController {
    
        @PostMapping("/downloadExcel")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadExcel(@RequestBody StringBuffer csvData) throws IOException {
            byte[] excelContent = generateExcelContent(csvData);
    
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "example.xlsx");
    
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(excelContent);
        }
    
        private byte[] generateExcelContent(StringBuffer csvData) throws IOException {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
    
            // Sample data for demonstration purposes
            csvData.append("Name,Age,Country\n");
            csvData.append("John,25,USA\n");
            csvData.append("Alice,30,Canada\n");
            csvData.append("Bob,22,UK\n");
    
            String[] lines = csvData.toString().split("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                String[] values = lines[i].split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(values[j]);
                }
            }
    
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            workbook.write(outputStream);
    
            // Ensure the workbook and outputStream are properly closed
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();
    
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Ajax code:

```js
    $.ajax({
    url: '/downloadExcel',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'example.xlsx';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error downloading Excel file:', textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Excel error when I try to open a file:

> We found a problem with some content in 'example.xlsx'. Do you want us
> to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
> workbook click yes or no

Click yes

> Excel cannot open the file 'example.xlsx' because the file format or
> file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
> corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Notes: I checked the excel file that is generated in controller to see if I can download and OPEN the file w/o sending to Ajax to make sure server side is generating the file in correct format. I WAS ABLE TO DOWNLOAD AND OPEN THE FILE EXCEL. Somehow file is getting corrupted when it goes AJAX. Please help as I am new to AJAX. thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type to a more explicit XLSX one? Quick web search suggests `application/vnd.ms-excel` might be the "official" one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to download the binary stream into JavaScript in the first place?  JavaScript cannot read the Excel - you want to pass control out of the browser to the Excel/similar don't you?  I think you may be overcomplicating this.

If you want a Web application to present to the user some way to download the spreadsheet content from your sever an then open it in Excel, you merely need to create something like this:

```
<form action="/downloadExcel" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" value="Open in Excel">
</form>
```